# Spark: Variant Datatype is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sqldatatypes, variant

While extracting the data from SQL Server of variant data type in Pyspark. i am getting a SQLServerException : "Variant datatype is not supported"

Please advice for any workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Converted the column datatype into `varchar` while fetching and thing worked

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,Code,20) into Code from DBTable
```