# jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, mssql-jdbc

I use pyspark 2.4.4 when I am getting the data from SQL Server I get `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported.`

What is needed to do? to fix this problem. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786605/spark-variant-datatype-is-not-supported#comment-formatting). But, I do not understand.

EDIT: 
The following is the code I use to create the error message:

```
for i in df['name']: mssql_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \ 
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:1433;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true") \ 
.option("dbtable", "[" + i + "]") \ 
.option("driver", 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver').load()
```

Comment: What is the code you run to get the data from SQL Server?

Comment: `for i in df['name']:
    mssql_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:1433;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true") \
        .option("dbtable", "[" + i + "]") \
        .option("driver", 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver').load()`

Comment: Some research is showing that the JDBC driver does not work with the sql_variant data type.  I wouldn't know how to fix this other than finding a replacement for JDBC on your end or a replacement fro sql_variant on the server's end.  I've upvoted for visibility, hopefully someone can help you out soon.

Comment: @Hoog re: "the JDBC driver does not work with the sql_variant data type" - Not true. [This test code](https://pastebin.com/phED8ebN) works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

This answer comes a bit late but might be of help to future searches for solution of that error.
I simply upgraded my connector from version 6.1.0.jre8 to 8.1.0.jre8-preview and the error was resolved.

You can check for latest version in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc).

Comment: I simply correcting the connector version of sql server 

        <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
             <version>9.2.1.jre8</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: This is the correct answer for me.
And be sure not to have dependency `<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId><artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>` left in your pom.xml !

Answer (score 3):

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
mssql-jdbc from version 6.3.x up to current all support "variant" data type. You just update dependency to resolve your problem.